# How to implement open api v3 keyboards (oneOf, anyOf) in springboot annotations of swagger v2 schema

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a springboot application with swagger v2(2.9.2). I want to implement inheritance concepts in swagger (/v2/api-docs).
In openapi v3 we have options like `oneOf` and `anyOf` for the implementation of polymorphism. How to do it in swagger v2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use vendor extenions to document oneOf/anyOf in OpenAPI/Swagger v2, e.g.

x-oneOf, x-anyOf

but likely these won't be recognized by any tools in the OpenAPI/Swagger ecosystem.

It's better to migrate to OpenAPI v3.